# Optional orElse throws NPE unexpectedly; taking null as a value

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

Function:

```
private static void printArray(int[] array, Optional<Integer> startIndex, Optional<Integer> endIndex) {
    for(Integer i = a.orElse(new Integer(0)); i<=endIndex.orElse(new Integer(array.length));i++) {
        System.out.print(array[i]+"  ");
    }
}
```

On passing a value like:

```
printArray(arr1, null, null);
```

*NPE is thrown*. Why `Optional.orElse` function is not creating a new Integer object? I checked on StackOverflow but couldn't find NPE from `orElse` being thrown. I find this behavior unexpected.

All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I'm not totally sure, but I think using `Oprional` as method argument or method return is an bad practice.

Comment: I don't quite understand why people tend to use lambda expressions even for simple tasks. Quite often it makes the code less readable and harder to debug, like here. Why don't you define primitive `int` instead of nullable `Integer`?

Comment: @Zorglube Actually `Optional` is mostly used as method arguments and return values. If not, where else to use it?

Comment: @jediz Where do you see lambda expressions in the question?

Comment: FWIW, never use an `Integer` as loop variable, as will perhaps create a lot of unwanted boxing/unboxing operations (not sure if JIT is clever enought to optimize that)

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov I use it in the method to handle an method return, but not as a method return.

Comment: @Zorglube: yes, passing Optionals as method arguments is ugly. flatMap makes it unnecessary.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should pass `Optional.empty()` instead of `null`:

```
printArray(arr1, Optional.empty(), Optional.empty());
```

If you pass `null`, it will fail with NPE because you call `orElse` on a `null` object (Optional has no special treatment in Java, it's just an ordinary object).

P.S. Use `OptionalInt` instead of `Optional<Integer>`

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void printArray(int[] array, Optional<Integer> startIndex, Optional<Integer> endIndex) {
    int from = Optional.ofNullable(startIndex).orElse(Optional.of(0)).orElse(0);
    int to = Optional.ofNullable(endIndex).orElse(Optional.of(array.length)).orElse(array.length);

    for (int i = from; i <= to; i++) {
        System.out.print(array[i] + "  ");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this and it works too but this is very complex. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: That is why you should avoid passing optionals into methods as a parameters........ or why you should avoid passing nulls into the methods..... Because if you do that - you defeats the whole purpose of optionals. KISS principle.

Answer (score -1):

First of all **you should not pass Optionals as a parameters into a method**, if you see the code which passes optionals into methods - change it, unwrap optionals in the place you are calling method.
Consider [this cheat sheet from Zeroturnaround](https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-8-best-practices-cheat-sheet/).

PS: Just for fun : My suggestion is if you are using an optionals here, so why do not to use streams? :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    printArray(array, OptionalInt.of(0), OptionalInt.empty());
    System.out.println();
    printArray(array, OptionalInt.of(1), OptionalInt.empty());
    System.out.println();
    printArray(array, OptionalInt.of(1), OptionalInt.of(2));
    System.out.println();

}

private static void printArray(int[] array, OptionalInt startIndex, OptionalInt endIndex) {
    int startIdx = startIndex.orElse(0);
    int endIdx = endIndex.orElse(array.length);

    if (endIdx < startIdx)
        return;

    Arrays.stream(array).skip(startIdx).limit(endIdx).forEach(n -> System.out.print(n + " "));
}
```

It gives us this output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 
2 3 4 5 
2 3
```

Comment: @NathanHughes what does “OP” mean?

Comment: @Pavel This is not at all worthy of an answer. Please delete it. OptionalInt has been already pointed out in the previous answer. Also, don't write answers just for fun. Please go to social platforms meant for it.

Comment: @StutiVerma you see... to pass optionals to the methods as a parameters in java - is a sign of code smell... And a sign of person who wrote it like that - does not know how to use optionals. So I have to point it out, whenever you like it or not. I’ve seen code like that a lot, written by my dear colleagues from sunny India...